# iterate through an a json value containing an array to pick an image string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am able to fetch values the db and pass it to a string array as shown

```
String[] strArrayCol = new String[6];
strArrayCol[4] = json_data.getString("images");
```

if you print the above you gets:

```
[{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/yi6ej6f524bepyujh49y.png"},{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/wendzj5atiks45c3zw00.png"},{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/rg04t5vcp4yxwdew677n.png"},{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/3yvy9f970vit2pxascv7.png"}]
```

my attempt is on performing something like

```
ArrayList<String[]> imgCol...
imgCol.add(strArrayCol );

 for (String [] val : imgCol){
                                System.out.println( val[4]);
                            }
```

let it prints

```
http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/yi6ej6f524bepyujh49y.png
http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/wendzj5atiks45c3zw00.png
http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/rg04t5vcp4yxwdew677n.png
http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/3yvy9f970vit2pxascv7.png
```

please how can I achieve this

Comment: your "code" looks fine, what is the error you getting?

Comment: there is no error, presently it prints this >>>> [{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/yi6ej6f524bepyujh49y.png"},{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/wendzj5atiks45c3zw00.png"},{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/rg04t5vcp4yxwdew677n.png"},{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/3yvy9f970vit2pxascv7.png"}] but I need it to print this >>> http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/yi6ej6f524bepyujh49y.png
http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/wendzj5atiks45c3zw00.png..................

Comment: the goal is to decode the image from that string variable

Comment: split each string string.split(""path":");

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code and explanation, it seems you are JSON object "images" is the below string:

```
{images:[{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/yi6ej6f524bepyujh49y.png"},{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/wendzj5atiks45c3zw00.png"},{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/rg04t5vcp4yxwdew677n.png"},{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/3yvy9f970vit2pxascv7.png"}])}
```

Which is a JSONArray for the value of images.., Your code should be like this to retrieve the value of path

I have removed extra backward slashes in the string.

```
JsonImplement.parseJson("{\"images\":[{\"path\":\"http://10.0.2.2:88//web/uploads/images/yi6ej6f524bepyujh49y.png\"},{\"path\":\"http://10.0.2.2:88//web/uploads/images/wendzj5atiks45c3zw00.png\"},{\"path\":\"http://10.0.2.2:88//web/uploads/images/rg04t5vcp4yxwdew677n.png\"},{\"path\":\"http://10.0.2.2:88//web/uploads/images/3yvy9f970vit2pxascv7.png\"}]}");
```

And  this is the logic I wrote in another method...

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);
JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("images");
for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
{
    JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
    System.out.println(obj2.get("path"));
}
```

This will give you output of image path's

```
http://10.0.2.2:88//web/uploads/images/yi6ej6f524bepyujh49y.png
http://10.0.2.2:88//web/uploads/images/wendzj5atiks45c3zw00.png
http://10.0.2.2:88//web/uploads/images/rg04t5vcp4yxwdew677n.png
http://10.0.2.2:88//web/uploads/images/3yvy9f970vit2pxascv7.png
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your image file names will always be formatted as follows:

```
{path}/{filename}
```

Then there is a simple technique to find the file name.

1. Find the last slash (/) character in the string.
2. The filename is everything that follows the last slash character.

For example:

```
http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/\/web\/uploads\/images\/yi6ej6f524bepyujh49y.png
```

has a "path" value of "http://10.0.2.2:88//web/uploads/images/"
and a "filename" value of "yi6ej6f524bepyujh49y.png"